# Current View - which view am I actually looking at?

Tags: list, web-part, list-view, data-view-web-part

I have a list with a few views.

There are web parts used that links to the List and one of it's views. However, I am trying to determine which one is the Current View.

I looked at the view ID Googles Dev Tool's Inspect option and see if I can find it the "Edit The Current View" link.

However, the view ID in the Edit page is not the same as any of the view ID's in the List.

So is there a way to find the exact view that the web part is referencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Current View** in SharePoint List Web Part (Apps Web Part) is not related to any list view in our SharePoint List.

As per my understanding, when you add the list web part on a SharePoint page it creates a copy of default view of your SharePoint list.

**Current View** is not updated when you change the view on the list itself. If you want to add/remove any column then you have to update the view on the web part.

However, If you want to show the custom view from list to SharePoint page then you can select the particular view from drop-down in web part properties.

Also, note that if you made any changes to the view on the list itself then it will not be reflected on the web part or vice versa.

Comment: Your explanation on what it is makes sense if I created this list with all the views.  .  My issue is, I took over this list with multiple views from someone else.  They did not leave any documentation or explanation on which views.  Some view's name are very close.  So I don't know which to choose in the drop down.  So I just went the  "Edit Current View" route and it appears to work.

Comment: Yes, If you want to add some specific filters or show some specific columns in your list web part then you can customize the Current View in list web part itself using `Edit Current View` link. This is the wise choice as it will not affect your existing list views at all. :)

Comment: Thank you @ganesh-sanap, as always!  I'll mark you as an answer since you explained what the Current View is (a copy of a default view...good to know).